# Squid Proxy behind Loadbalancer delivers 403

Tags: proxy, load-balancing, acl, squid

first let me describe my environment and then my problem.
I have 2 Frontend Server with Apache and Squid Proxy installed on it.
Then I got 4 Hybris Server which uses first Squid Proxy.

Now that I installed two Squid Server I want to get more high availability.
So I implemented a Loadbalancer which balances two Squid Server and allows access from the 4 Hybris Server.

If I try telnet LoadbalancerIP 3128 then I get answer.
also if I try http_proxy to one of the Squid Server directly.

But if I use http_proxy on the loadbalancer IP then I get 403.

It sounds like that the Loadbalancer IP is not allowed to access, so I added it into my acl and allowed it in the Configuration but the results are the same.

All I find at google are loadbalanced Squids but not two Squids behind a Loadbalancer.

Greeting Fide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of my Problem is so simple that it hurts.
The important fact to know that a F5 uses more than one IP is the key.
I looked for all the IPs and added them as ACL into the squid and voila it worked.

Greeting Fide